# Show APEX$ROW_ACTION on button click in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an editable Interactive Grid in a page. My page is read only on page load, and there is a separate button 'EDIT' in page, by clicking on which page becomes editable. At the moment, APEX$ROW_ACTION column of IG is visible on page load by default. I want to APEX$ROW_ACTION column only after user clicks on EDIT button.

NOTE : This EDIT button is not the default Edit button of IG

Comment: I don't really have an answer, just a clarifying question that might help you find the solution.

It sounds like you want:

 1. Page On-Load Javascript that hides the column
 2. The Edit button runs a dynamic action of Javascript to show the column

Are you stuck at identifying the APEX$ROW_ACTION column ID? Or is it hiding the column values for each row?

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct. I tried using via static ID in APEX$ROW_ACTION column, but somehow any JS I write for that column, ends up not displaying whole page. I tried ```$( "#emp_ig_grid_vc" ).grid( "hideColumn", "APEX$ROW_ACTION" );``` This also does not display IG at all. But if instead of APEX$ROW_ACTION I use any other column, then it works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but my Javascript is still too weak to solve this (I keep meaning to learn more!). How about going at this a different way?

What if you used 2 grids on the same page, one read-only and the other editable?

1. The page defaults to displaying the Read-only
2. They click the Edit button
3. That hides the Read-only and displays the Editable

This Apex Forum comment describes getting around the 1 IG per page limitation: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/12587490#Comment_12587490